# how to filter out an element based on multiple values with one of them being boolean in js?

Tags: javascript

I have some array of obj like

```
    const someThing = [
    { appId: 17146, id: 1, primaryLabel: "Command 1", isCommand : true},
    { appId: 17146, id: 1, primaryLabel: "Menu1", isCommand : false},
    ]
```

I may have to delete some entry based on id and isCommand. 
here the id can be same for the menu and command but isCommand can be different.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is and how you've attempted to solve it, with a reproducible example if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `filter` method here.

For example:

```
someThing.filter(item => item.isCommand && item.id !== 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the entries that you want to have in your resulting array.

```
someThing.filter(thing => thing.isCommand === true && thing.primaryLabel === "Command 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` method on arrays is your best bet:

```js
const someThing = [{
    appId: 17146,
    id: 1,
    primaryLabel: "Command 1",
    isCommand: true
  },
  {
    appId: 17146,
    id: 1,
    primaryLabel: "Menu1",
    isCommand: false
  },
];

const output = someThing.filter(({ isCommand, id }) => isCommand && id == 1);

console.log(output);
```

You can easily modify the conditions to your liking for different filters as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a traditional for loop, but I recommend you using a higher order function *filter* as follows:

```
const newArray = someThing.filter(item => item.id < 10 && item.isCommand == true);
```

This will return an array with *id* less than 10 and *isCommand* is true